# How to not have a signature inserted in new emails in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app

I'd like to have signatures configured as part of my preferences in Apple Mail, but not have them auto-inserted whenever I create a new email. Is there a way to default to "None", but still have signatures associated with the account?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the signature to your email account but still have the default set to none.

[image]

If you create a new mail now, it will have no signature by default but you'll still have the dropdown at top right to select one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way using a little trick.

In your Signatures make a new one call it none, but do not write anything in the Signature field and make that one default.

Now when you write a email it will normally not show a signature, but you can click on and select the actual signature.

see this for more detailed answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144580/46541